# Does bootstrap support col in row without container

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, col

I'm using bootstrap 4.6.0 and wondering if next usage is supported. Everything works, but shouldn't I use another container:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <!-- <div class="container-fluid"> -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">A1</div>
        <div class="col-6">A2sdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsd fgsdfgdfgsdfgsdfg</div>
      </div>
      <!-- </div> -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <h1>Blasdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsd sdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsd</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Are there any drawbacks for this usage? Inspecting bootstrap `.container-fluid`, it has only this style:

```
.container, .container-fluid, .container-xl, .container-lg, .container-md, .container-sm {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use `container` or `container-fluid` classes to nest rows.

Documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/#nesting

```css
.bd-example-row .row>.col, .bd-example-row .row>[class^="col-"] {
    padding-top: .75rem;
    padding-bottom: .75rem;
    background-color: rgba(86,61,124,0.15);
    border: 1px solid rgba(86,61,124,0.2);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container bd-example-row">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      Level 1: .col-sm-9
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8 col-sm-6">
          Level 2: .col-8 .col-sm-6
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 col-sm-6">
          Level 2: .col-4 .col-sm-6
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You added link to official documentation with example of using nesting. Thnx.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between .container and .container fluid is that the .container has a max-width style rule applied. This is set at 1170px which when you add the 15px padding left and right, gives a total column width of 1200px.

The margin:0 auto in the styling you provided means that the .container 1200px column is horizontally centred in the viewport.

This is the only difference between them and so it’s fine to use one or the other. The .container-fluid is identical except it doesn’t have the max-width styling and so takes the full width of the viewport.

All you are doing is applying a nested row in your column, which is required to offset the left and right padding of the col. this correct- otherwise you would have left and right gutters of 30 px. But you only need one parent div with either .container or .container-fluid class.

Answer (score 1):

Only the outermost row needs a container. As shown in the docs for "[Nesting](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/#nesting)" the inner rows are placed directly inside the column.

Additionally, the [container docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/overview/#containers) state...

> "While containers can be nested, most layouts do not require a nested
> container."

Comment: You answer is correct, thnx for pointing to Nesting documentation. Your and @naveen answers are correct, but I can only accept one answer as correct.